# how to set startPosition.current when clicked on prev/next arrows on react-owl-carousel

Tags: reactjs, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

How can i set **startPosition.current** in react-owl-carowsel when clicked on prev/next arows.
its working for onDragged prop, but i can find any event on prev/next click on their [website](https://github.com/laurenchen0631/react-owl-carousel)

this is my code

```
        <OwlCarousel
          items={4}
          className="owl-theme"
          loop
          dots={false}
          nav
          margin={30}
          responsive={responsive}
          startPosition={startPosition2.current}
          onDragged={({ item, page }) => {
            startPosition2.current = item.index - page.size;
          }}
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

There no attachable event for Next or Prev. Callback for this ones, that may help is `onTranslated` But it is no listen where carousel was translated - to next or to prev. But it works for click on arrows.
if you want individual events for Next and other for Prev click, then it must be individual script working with `click` on each arrow, i think.